# Where did I not close the stream?

Tags: c#

there is a code

1. When the chatlist.json does not exist, it is created and an empty list is placed in it
2. When the chatslist.json exists, it is deserialized

   ```
    private async Task<ChatsInfo> ReadChatsList()
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(chatsListPath);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(chatsListPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                ChatsInfo chatsList = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ChatsInfo>(fs);
                fs.Close();
                return chatsList;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ChatsInfo emptylist = new ChatsInfo();
            emptylist.activedChats = new List<long>();
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(chatsListPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<ChatsInfo>(fs, emptylist, new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    WriteIndented = true
                });
                fs.Close();
            }
            return emptylist;
        }
    private async void SerializeChatsList(ChatsInfo data)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(chatsListPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<ChatsInfo>(fs, data, new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                WriteIndented = true
            });
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
    private async Task<bool> ChatInTheList(long chat_id)
    {
        ChatsInfo chatsList = await ReadChatsList();
        return chatsList.activedChats.Contains(chat_id);
    }
   ```

There is a condition

```
        if(!await ChatInTheList(message.Chat.Id))
        {
            AddChatInList(message.Chat.Id);
        }
```

An error occurs, at which the error appears

```
System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file
'C:\Users\User\source\repos\tgbot\bin\linux-x64\netcoreapp3.1\chatslist.json'
because it is being used by another process."

Initially, this exception was created in this call stack:
    [External code]
    tgbot.Bot.ReadChatsList() в Bot.cs
    [External code]
    tgbot.Bot.ChatInTheList(long) в Bot.cs
    [External code]
    tgbot.Bot.OnMessageReceived(object, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs) в Bot.cs
```

Why doesn't one of the threads close? Where did I go wrong?

@PanagiotisKanavos

```
    private async void AddChatInList(long chat_id)
    {
        ChatsInfo chatsList = await ReadChatsList();
        chatsList.activedChats.Add(chat_id);
        SerializeChatsList(chatsList);

    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should remove all the `fs.Close`.

Comment: `async void` is a bug. It's only meant for event handlers. Use `async Task` and *await* the method. Otherwise you have no control over when that method actually runs - the application may exit before that method had a chance to complete

Comment: It is entirely possible that an external event handler (such as `OnMessageReceived`) will fire while you are accessing the file, which is specifically because you made the file access async. If your file access was synchronous, the event handler would not be able to intervene (unless you are fiddling with threads manually, which you don't seem to do).

Comment: `Can't be awaited` here means that your code will open a stream inside `SerializeChatsList` and *continue with the next method*, leaving the stream open. You didn't post the code that calls `SerializeChatsList` so one can only guess it's opening the same file twice

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
So far, SerializeChatsList is only used in this method
I will give it in the question for ease of reading

Comment: There's your bug then. And `AddChatInList` itself isn't awaited either. The way that code is written would result in multiple attempts to open the stream even with a single thread

Comment: Ie as I understand it, the AddChatInList method should be synchronous?

Comment: @pijio No, it must be a `Task` and it must be awaited where it's called. And the `SerializeChatsList` call inside it must be awaited too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't await `AddChatInList()`, so while that method is running, another method is trying to access the file.

Also, do you want to thrash your SSD? Because this is how you'll thrash your SSD. (No, not really, those things can write a lot of data, but...) every chat line results in a read-write operation of the entire file, which will grow with each chat message. Your system will become unbearably slow.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to keep the method call to a minimum

Comment: that's why it's best to name all asynchronous methods `SomeMethodAsync`.